# Call Process in C# with String args[]

Tags: c#, process, program-entry-point

I want to call a Process from C# with multiple parameters.

When i call:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
...
info.Arguments = "argument";
Process.Start(info);
```

i can only set a `String` as attribute. (Same to all types of the Start method)

Is there a way to set a `String[]` as arguments or how does this `String` getting interpreted?

Because on the other side

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

i am getting a `String[]`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Program arguments are separated by spaces in most, if not all, OS's. It's .NET that splits this into an array of strings for convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to set a String[] as argument?

No you can't do this, since the type of `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` is `string`. Hence you can assign to it an array of strings.

You could pass to this string the parameters as follows:

```
info.Arguments = "argument1 argument2 argument3";
```

and your .exe will be executed as you were passing an array of strings with elements (`argument1`,`argument2`,`argument3`).

Answer (score 3):

Technically you can do it like that:

```
  string[] args = new String[] {"argument1", "argument2", "argument3"};

  ...

  info.Arguments = String.Join(" ", args);
```

the restriction is that args should not have arguments with spaces